# See what path aliases are set up with Drush?

Tags: drush

Ive installed Drush and my local system is a Mac. It seems to have worked as when I type `drush` into the terminal a long list of commands comes up.

When I type `drush cc all` I get the message `'drush' cache was cleared` . Does that mean my path aliases are set up? Or could I be getting a false success message? I have a number of Drupal sites locally and I dont know which (if any) is having its cache cleared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to either be within a drupal doc_root (aka apache verbiage) or have properly configured drush site aliases for commands to work:

Eg, if your site lives at /var/www/

```
cd /var/www/
drush cc all
```

Or if you have setup a [drush site alias](http://drush.ws/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php) of @local, then from anywhere on your system:

```
drush @local cc all
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning that `'drush' cache was cleared` is the message you get when running `drush cc all` _outside_ of a Drupal doc root. It clear's Drush's own internal cache. I've learned to use it as a quick indicator that I'm not in the folder I think I am

Comment: I have a follow up question that ive asked here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88454/how-to-run-a-drush-command-with-the-full-site-path

Answer (score 2):

To answer what in the title of the question is asked:

```
drush site-alias
```

lists all site aliases you have defined.