# How to run a Drush command with the full site path?

Tags: drush

Im trying to get Drush working. When I type 'drush' into terminal I get a list of commands so I know its installed.

I dont have any path aliases set up yet so im trying to use the full path. When I type the following into terminal:

```
cd path-to-my-site drush dl views
```

I get this message:

```
unknown:omegav3 my-user-name$
```

Should the path-to-my-site be the base path? Im working locally with MAMP. I have different sites that arnt in the root folder so my local url for this site im trying to target is:

```
http://localhost:8888/omega/omegav3/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd path-to-my-site drush dl views
```

Means you're trying to change directory into "path-to-my-site drush dl views" folder. You need to separately type the commands

```
cd path-to-my-site
drush dl views
```

Or you can use double ampersand or semi-colon to separate the commands. Double ampersand means previous command must succeed before the second executes, whereas semi-colon just means execute next command regardless of success or error on previous command:

```
cd path-to-my-site && drush dl views

cd path-to-my-site; drush dl views
```

Comment: or `drush --root=/path/to/my/site --uri=mysite.org drush dl views`

Comment: @greg_1_anderson is it intentional to have 2 `drush` words in that same line? Or is it a mistake? Looks like it should be `drush --root=/path/to/my/site --uri=mysite.org dl views` (note: no `drush` in front of `dl`)

Comment: Sorry -- the second drush was in fact a typo!

Comment: It seems to me that @greg_1_anderson's comment should be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: What I intended to say was:  `drush --root=/path/to/my/site --uri=mysite.org && drush dl views`.  The correction above was not correct!  I just put that in as a comment because it did not add very much to the answer, but the fact that comments cannot be edited is problematic. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 11):

Your command should be like:

```
drush dl views
```

or:

```
drush dl views -r /path/to/site/root
```

To get help manual for commands run:

```
drush help
```

Please find better explanation for drush commands at [GitHub](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush).

Comment: Thanks, but im getting the same result.

Comment: check the updated asnwer

Answer (score 9):

- On your command line, from anywhere, run:

> $ drush --root=/path/to/drupal-installation --uri=youdomain.com dl views

- In case you are already at /path/to/drupal-installation just run:

> $ drush --uri=youdomain.com dl views

- In case you are even further ahead at /path/to/drupal-installation/sites/youdomain.com than just run:

> $ drush dl views

See also how to run a script at [How to execute php script using drush?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9837/how-to-execute-php-script-using-drush/162692#162692)